# Error : cannot be cast to shade.com.datastax.spark.connector.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

Me using spark-sql 2.4.1 with spark-cassandra-connector_2.11 with java8.

While saving data into C* table , I am getting below error, any clue how to fix this issue?

Its occurring while running on AWS EC2 cluster.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture cannot be cast to shade.com.datastax.spark.connector.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncExecutor.com$datastax$spark$connector$writer$AsyncExecutor$$tryFuture$1(AsyncExecutor.scala:38)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncExecutor.executeAsync(AsyncExecutor.scala:71)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$writeInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(TableWriter.scala:234)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$writeInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(TableWriter.scala:233)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.GroupingBatchBuilder.foreach(GroupingBatchBuilder.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$writeInternal$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:233)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$writeInternal$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:210)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:112)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:145)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.writeInternal(TableWriter.scala:210)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.insert(TableWriter.scala:197)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:183)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
```

Here is the pom.xml file i am using:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>snpmi</groupId>
<artifactId>ca-datamigration</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<name>ca-datamigration</name>
<description>ca-datamigration</description>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
  <build.scope>provided</build.scope>
  <app.jar.name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-package</app.jar.name>

  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target> 

  <scala.version>2.11.12</scala.version>
  <scala.compat.version>2.11</scala.compat.version>
  <spark.version>2.4.1</spark.version>
  <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
  <jackson.version>2.6.7</jackson.version>
  <app.jar.name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-package</app.jar.name>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>${scala.version}</version>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-tags_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-csv_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
    <artifactId>config</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.nscala-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>nscala-time_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.jcazevedo</groupId>
    <artifactId>moultingyaml_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr166e</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    <version>1.23</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
  <plugins>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Tried with removing explicit netty as below.

**For Uberjar**

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
      <filters>
        <filter>
          <artifact>*:*</artifact>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </filter>
      </filters>
    </configuration>
          </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Does this fine or do I need to do anything?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need explicitly include Netty?

Comment: see the answer - first time I missed that you included driver explicitly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove following dependency from your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Spark Cassandra connector (SCC) contains all pieces to connect to Cassandra, so you don't need to include driver.

And you're using wrong version of spark connector - the version that you're using is for use with `--packages` flag of `spark-submit`, not for linking. Try to use [following version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11/2.4.1):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, please note, that releases of the SCC doesn't match precisely to Spark versions. Current Spark version is 2.4.3, and SCC version is 2.4.1.

Comment: run `mvn dependency:tree` and check maybe the driver core is pulled from somewhere else...

Comment: if you're using it's via submit, then you don't need to put it into `pom.xml`... Basically - there are 2 versions: one that I pointed - it's for direct linking, etc. And 2nd (that you're using) - it's for use with `--packages` - it's an uberjar with connector. Just put the dependency as I described, and build uberjar. Also, look to the example on the Github that I've pointed to - it works without any problem

Comment: for example, like here: https://github.com/datastax/SparkBuildExamples/blob/master/java/maven/oss/pom.xml